# C error: unknown type name 'FILE', in function

Tags: c, function, pointers, error-handling

In my header file, where I put all my function declarations I have added

```
void record(FILE *fptr);`
```

However, I keep getting the error

> unknown type name 'FILE', in function`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, where did you tell the computer what `FILE` is?

Comment: You have to include stdio.h _in the header file_.

Comment: You have to include studio.h

Comment: Add  include of `stdio.h`  in the top of your the header file, just after the guard section. i.e. `#ifndef MY_H_INC #define MY_H_INC  #include <stdio.h> ... void record(FILE* fptr); .... #endif /*MY_H_INC*/`

Answer (score 0):

`FILE` is not a primitive or built-in type in C. It is a specially defined type in `stdio.h`, so you must have an `#include <stdio.h>` in your code above where your using `FILE*` pointers.